# CakePhp mysql raw query error

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm new to cakephp. I'm trying to search through mysql tables. I want to use nested query.

```
 class TableController extends AppController{  
 .
 .
 public function show(){
    $this->set('discouns', $this->DiscounsController->query("SELECT * FROM discoun as Discoun WHERE gcil_id = 1"));//(SELECT id FROM gcils WHERE genre = 'Shoes' AND company_name = 'Adidas')"));
}
```

}
Error:

```
 Error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

I've also tried

```
public function show(){
    $this->DiscounsController->query("SELECT * FROM count as Count WHERE ctr_id = (SELECT id FROM ctrs WHERE genre = 'Shoes' AND company_name = 'Adidas')");
}
```

Error:

```
 Error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephppro\myapp\Controller\CountsController.php

Please help. I've been trying this for last few hours. :/

Comment: Basically I want to implement nested search as you can see through my raw query. I'm finding it easier to use mysql queries rather than using cakephp queries but I don't know if there's any prob with that.

Comment: Error raised in code part where you use `discouns`. Show that part.

Comment: I realized that error & have edited accordingly.

Comment: Why would you write plain sql, when you are using Cake which would be able to handle this via find() wrapper? also why in the world would you try to run query() on a controller when it cleary is a model method?

Comment: Ok, you seem to be very new to the topic. Still - I strongly advice you to read the manual http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html and doing the online tutorials. your code is faulty from the beginning to the end, there is just no way one could answer you without writing a complete and personalized tutorial for you.

Comment: Done. Just had some errors with my variables' name.

Comment: discoun <- shouldn't that table name be discount or discounts maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are a few problems with your code.

Firstly, you are trying to call the `query()` method on a *Controller*, whereas you should be executing it on a **Model**, as it is models that handle database queries and the controller should simply be used to call these methods to get the data and pass them to the view.

The second thing is that you are executing a very simple SQL query raw instead of using [CakePHPs built in functions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) <- Be sure to read this page in full.

Now for your problem, as long as you have setup your [model relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) correctly and followed the correct naming conventions, this should be your code to run your SQL query from that controller:

```
public function show(){
    $this->set('discouns', $this->Discouns->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'gcil_id' => 1,
            'genre' => 'shoes',
            'company_name' => 'Adidas'
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: Yup.. I had corrected my code. But thanks man.. :)
Also, I have more complex queries to search. I was just trying it on an easier one. :)

Answer (score 0):

`query()` is not a Controller, but a Model method. That's what the error (*Call to a member function on a non-object*) is trying to tell you.

So the correct call would be:

`$this->Discount->query()`

But you are calling this in a `TableController`, so unless `Table` and `Discount` have [some type of relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), you won't be able to call `query()`.

If the `Table` does have a relationship defined you will be able to call:

`$this->Table->Discount->query()`

Please not that `query()` is only used when performing complex SQL queries in scenarios where [the standard methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) (`find`, `save`, `delete`, etc.) are less practical.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Counts->find('all',array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'ctrs.genre' => 'Shoes',
    'ctrs.company_name' => 'Adidas'
  ), 'recursive' => 1
));
```

The above is with tables named counts and ctrs.

This is assuming you have the model set up to have some sort of relationship between the counts table and the ctrs table.  It's kind of hard to tell in your code exactly what you tables are.

The CakePHP book should have all the answers you need.  One of the reasons to run CakePHP over regular PHP is the FIND statement.  Once you have your models set up correctly, using the find statement should be really easy.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html